# How to connect to IntelliJ Ultimate's LocalHost MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea, connection

I went to Database > + > Data Source > MySQL

Here's what my panel looks like:
[image]

This is the error:

```
[08S01]
    Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
```

and here's my connection file:

```
package sample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection
{

    private static Connection connection;
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "root";
    private static final String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user";

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            try
            {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(database, user, password);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Could not open database.");
                System.exit(1);

            }
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

What could be my problem? I tried searching up for what others have tried but none of them seemed to work and I had to make several copies of my entire project because I kept messing things up trying those solutions to no avail. More specifically [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

Comment: Do you have the server running and listening on port 3306? Veirfy with the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview. Can you connect to this server using any other tools? Is there any firewall that can block the connection?

Comment: @CrazyCoder let's say it's not running, how would I make the server run on port 3306?

Comment: Did you try to follow https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/starting-server.html?

Comment: @CrazyCoder dang, I did not do either of those. I followed this tutorial and that's all I thought i had to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yiL99KFeng&t=779s

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, ill look in to it and give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have MySQL server [installed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html) and [running](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/starting-server.html) to be able to connect to it from the other apps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your program did not run and so you went to configure some datasource in Intelij to make a connection with your Database.

If that is the case then

1. Your db is not reachable. Check if it is running and if all information provided here is correctly.
2. You don't need to set a InteliJ Datasource for your program to run. That is only for you to execute sql scripts using Intelij. It has nothing to do with some program that you develop using java which connects to that database.

Comment: no program was running fine before. I just wanted to add a database and I looked up a tutorrial on how to do that and they said add data source and mysql and that was it. no mention of the connection file

Comment: so you intend to make a database run from that connection file?

Comment: yea that was the intention, i tired following this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yiL99KFeng&t=779s

Comment: No database will not start that way. It is a different program that you have to install in your pc and execute and configure. Nothing to do with java and Intelij

Comment: thank you, that was the problem crazycoder told me